# ODE) Uniqueness-Existence Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

---

> Find a nontrivial solution of the initial-value problem $y' = ty^a$, $y(0)=0$, $a>1$. Does this violate Theorem 2'? Explain.

- Theorem 2' : Let $f$ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ be continuous in the rectangle $R: t_0 ≤ t ≤ t_0 + a$, $|y-y_0| ≤ b$. Compute 
  $$
  M = \max_{(t,y) \in R}|f(t,y)|, \quad\text{  and set }\quad\alpha = \min\left(a, \frac bM\right).
  $$
  Then, the initial value problem $y'=f(t,y)$, $y(t_0) = y_0$ has a ***unique solution $y(t)$ on the interval $t_0 ≤ t ≤ t_0 + a$.***

---

I found a nontrivial solution by the separation  of variables, and the solution is this : 
$$
y(t) = \left(\frac {t^2(1-a)}{2}\right)^{\frac {1}{1-a}}
$$

But, I have no idea from here. How do I prove that this doesn't violate the theorem? How should I set the range of t? How can a trivial solution $y(t)=0$ can be unique in this scheme?

Please help me, and great thanks!

[Reference : Martin Braun - Differential Equations and Their Applications, p.81.]

Comment: $f(y,t)=ty^a$, so $df/dy=aty^{a-1}$. Since $a-1>0$, $f$ and $df/dy$ are continuous in any rectangle of the form $[-b,b]  \times [0,x]$

Comment: @dgrasines517 That would imply the theorem held,  but there's a second solution,  y(t)=0

Comment: @dgrasines517 Thanks a lot! But as Alan thankfully points out, I' m not sure how can we say a solution is unique when y(t)=0 is also a solution.. Thanks!

Comment: @ATP Note that, as $1-a<0$,  your solution is not defined at $t=0$. When you do separation of variables,  you need to divide by $y^a$, but, by your initial condition, you are dividing by zero

Comment: @dgrasines517 I get your point! Help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution does not satisfy $y(0)=0$ because $1-a<0$. Are you sure that $a>1$?

Comment: I think the book has a mistake in this exercise, and it should have $0 < a < 1$ instead of $a>1$. With $0<a<1$, the OP's solution works; and $\partial f/\partial y$ is discontinuous at $y=0$.